# setUserData not executing script for aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, user-data, cloud-init

I'm trying to figure out how to get cloud-init to execute a script. At the moment I have a file called myscript which reads

## !/bin/sh

echo 'Hello world - I just executed user-data!' > /root/helloworld
sudo mkdir scripttest

Then in my Java code I have 
    String usrdata = new String();
    usrdata= "myscript";
    req.setUserData(usrdata);
    req.setUserData(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(usrdata.getBytes()));

```
result= client.runInstances(req);
```

This doesn't seem to be working when I ssh into the instance I'm running. Any thoughts why?

Comment: There should be a pound(#) in front of !/bin/sh

Answer (score 0):

The question has some formatting issues, so I hope I am understanding correctly...

I have never used cloud-init from java, but I can see some issues:

- the scripts will run as root.  So the `sudo mkdir scripttest` should just be `mkdir scripttest`
- usrdata seems to be a string with value `myscript`.  I expect it should rather be the base64 encoded **contents** of `myscript`.